# System.ArgumentException: Could not find the sitemap node with URL '/_layouts/WebAnalytics/WebAppSelection.aspx'

Tags: master-page, web-analytics

I've made a custom master page for my SharePoint site and it works fine on all the pages that I've checked except for the Web Analytics pages.  I get the following error in the logs when I go there:

> System.ArgumentException: Could not find the sitemap node with URL
>   '/_layouts/WebAnalytics/WebAppSelection.aspx'

How can I fix my master page so that this error does not occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found instructions in this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/2022cff0-e2cf-4702-bb2a-17dc91dd4247) on how to fix the problem.  It turns out that I had moved my QuickLaunchDataSource before the TopNavigationDataSource.  Once I moved the two controls into the correct order everything worked fine on that page.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using custom master page and sharepoint 2010, just remove the control that used '/_layouts/WebAnalytics/WebAppSelection.aspx' as StartingNodeUrl.

```
<%--<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar">
    <SharePoint:VersionedPlaceHolder UIVersion="4" runat="server">
        <div class="ms-quicklaunchouter">
            <div class="ms-quickLaunch" style="width:100%">
                <SharePoint:AspMenu
                    id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                    DataSourceID="siteMapDataSource" 
                    runat="server" 
                    EnableViewState="false"
                    UseSimpleRendering="true"
                    CssClass="s4-ql"
                    Orientation="Vertical" 
                    StaticDisplayLevels="3"
                    >
                </SharePoint:AspMenu>
                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDataSource" runat="server" SiteMapProvider="SPXmlContentMapProvider" StartingNodeUrl ="/_layouts/WebAnalytics/WebAppSelection.aspx" ShowStartingNode="false"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </SharePoint:VersionedPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>--%>
```

Control Location:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\WebAnalytics\Report.aspx

Answer (score 1):

## Here's a quick fix

#### Open this file:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\WebAnalytics\Report.aspx
```

#### Change:

```
DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"
```

#### To:

```
MasterPageFile="/_layouts/v4.master"
```

**Note:** This will force the analytics report to use v4.master instead of your custom master page, so you will lose your customized UI/branding when viewing analytics.